How to access the data from a POST in Nextjs
I am trying to access my body from the request but for some reason these are both undeinfed.
Here is the payload:
{ "timeEntries":
   [],
   "violations":[]
 }

export const POST = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { timeEntries, violations } = req.body
  console.info(timeEntries, violations) // undefined 


In Next.js, when handling POST requests in an API route, the request body is not automatically parsed. You need to use req.json() to parse the body, especially if you're using the app directory and next's built-in request handling.
Update your code like this:
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
  const body = await req.json(); // Parse the JSON body
  const { timeEntries, violations } = body;
  console.info(timeEntries, violations); // Should now log the correct values
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Success" });
};


Thanks, seems I cannot get it working with Typescript, but it does work
